# Evaluate Clojure namespace in *nrepl* buffer in emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

After creating a project with `lein new`, I open my `core.clj` in emacs and launch `nrepl`.

The `*nrepl*` buffer shows up and looks something like this:

```
; nREPL 0.1.6-preview
user>
```

Okay, but now I want to change the namespace, so I decide to evaluate or `C-c C-e` the namespace expression. Assume the expression in `core.clj` looks something like this:

```
(ns my-project.core)
```

Yet, nothing happens in the `*nrepl*` buffer. If I want, I can evaluate the namespace expression by entering it directly inside the `*nrepl*` buffer, and everything runs smoothly.

My question is: Why wouldn't I be able to evaluate a namespace expression by using `C-c C-e`? And if this is the normal, and correct behavior, I would like to know its rationale as well as an elisp workaround to get my desired behavior.

Comment: Evaluating the namespace form doesn't blast you into the namespace. Use `(in-ns 'my-project.core)` or the short-cut of Michiel's answer-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type C-c M-n:

https://github.com/clojure-emacs/nrepl.el

Switch the namespace of the repl buffer to the namespace of the current buffer.